# GAE Golang - queries not returning data right after it is saved

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing a Google App Engine Go application and I'm having problem in testing some functionality. [Here is some sample code.](https://github.com/ThePiachu/DatastoreQueryTest) The problem is as follows:

1. I create a new item and save it to datastore
2. I make a search query for that item immediately after (for example, getting all items in the namespace)
3. The item is not there

If I query for the item later (say, in subsequent pages), the item is found normally. I understand this behaviour might be intentional for apps deployed on GAE, but I would expect the local datastore to be instantly good for queries.

Is there any way I can force the datastore to consolidate and be good for such queries?

Comment: This is where you would start shifting your thought process from CRUD to a more Task-Based UI.

Answer (score 3):

This is called eventual consistency, and it's a feature of App Engine's Datastore.

You can use a get method instead of a query to test if an entity has been saved.

In Java we can set the desired behavior of a local datastore by changing a run parameter:

> By default, the local datastore is configured to simulate the
>   consistency model of the High Replication Datastore, with the
>   percentage of datastore writes that are not immediately visible in
>   global queries set to 10%.
>
> To adjust this level of consistency, set the
>   datastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct system
>   property with a value corresponding to the amount of eventual
>   consistency you want your application to see.

I could not find something similar for Go.

Comment: You can change the consistency parameter, but you should definitely **not**. The whole point of this is that it simulates worse-case performance in production: if you change it, you won't test the behaviour of your app when faced with eventual consistency.

Comment: @DanielRoseman My system is built to handle eventual consistency, but for testing it's rather annoying for the test to be "run this test, it will fail the first time, but if you run it again it should pass" sort of thing. When I'm testing my functions that rely on queries (which can't be changed), I would like to be able to feed the datastore some test data and test that on the spot rather than be dealing with fuzzy chances during testing.

Comment: I agree with Daniel that tests are more useful when they follow the production use patterns. If you have save-query sequence in production, you will run into the same problem as in testing (I once did with a scheduling app). And if you don't use it in production, then save-get sequence will serve your testing needs.